# ExpressionEngine 2 feed parser and the {title} conflict

Tags: rss, expressionengine

Is there a way of disabling the `{title}` tag in ExpressionEngine 2? My client needs just one custom field, `{rss_feed}`, to add content.

I use the [AJW Feed Parser](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/feed-parser) Add-On to parse RSS feeds. The client just wants to add a RSS/Atom feed link in order for the web page to be populated with that specific feed.

The problem is that there's a conflict between the ExpressionEngine entry `{title}` and the `{title}` field from the AJW Feed Parser Add-On.

When I use the `{title}` template variable, the output is from ExpressionEngine's default `{title}` field not the AJW Feed Parser `{title}`.

My code looks like this:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="blog" limit="1" dynamic="on" category="{embed:category}"}
    {exp:ajw_feedparser url="{blog_rss}" itempath="/feed/entry" cache_refresh="60" limit="1"}  
        <article>
            <header>
                <h1>{title}</h1>
                <time>{published format="%l, %j %F %Y at %G:%i"}</time>
                <a href="{author/uri}">{author/name}</a>
            </header>
            {content}
        </article>
    {/exp:ajw_feedparser} 
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Is there another way of doing this with PHP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is why add-ons should include a "prefix" parameter, to avoid variable collisions like this.

Regardless, you can solve this with an embed.

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="blog" limit="1" dynamic="on" category="{embed:category}"}
    {embed="_embeds/blog_feed" url="{blog_rss}"}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Then your **_embeds/blog_feed** template looks like this:

```
{exp:ajw_feedparser url="{embed:url_param}" itempath="/feed/entry" cache_refresh="60" limit="1"}  
    <article>
      <header>
        <h1>{title}</h1>
        <time datetime="2011-01-20T06:20:00-00:00">{published format="%l, %j %F %Y at %G:%i"}</time>
        <a href="{author/uri}">{author/name}</a>
      </header>
        {content}
    </article>
{/exp:ajw_feedparser}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that fixed it but I've got a new problem now.

I have categories and in each category I display the latest 3 blog posts of a specific RSS Feed. I have the 3 titles/name/time showing but the link to each of those isn't working:

I display those lists by:

    {exp:channel:entries channel="blog" limit="3" dynamic="on" category="{category_id}" }
    {embed="blog/feeds" my_rss="{blog_rss}"}       
    {/exp:channel:entries}

Inside blog/feeds the link looks like this:

    <a href="{path="blog/blog_item/"}">{title}</a>

Thank you !

Comment: What is the link **blog/blog_entry** to exactly? A channel entry? I'm not following. Maybe create a new question for this specific issue?

Comment: Where is the link supposed to go to? What are you expecting to get appended to **blog/blog_entry** ... an entry_id? Or is it related to the RSS feed, not a channel entry?

Comment: Been looking for this solution for a long time, was very helpful. Thanks!